# Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.3 status: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, karate

I have a settings.xml and a JFrog app that contains all dependencies.

When I ran: `mvn clean install` from cmd line I obtain the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project karate-demo: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.intuit.karate:karate-demo:jar:0.9.6: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springf

ramework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:jar:1.5.16.RELEASE -> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.16.RELEASE -> org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.6.Fin

al: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.6.Final: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.3 from/to public_l

ocal (https://aorgartifactoryxxxx/artifactory/mvn-public-local): authentication failed for https://orgartifactoryxxxx/artifactory/mvn-public-local/org/jboss/shrinkwrap

/shrinkwrap-bom/1.2.3/shrinkwrap-bom-1.2.3.pom, status: 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: no idea. please note that karate 0.9.6 is very old and not supported anymore

Answer (score 1):

The error **Failed to read artifact descriptor** returned with HTTP 401 indicates an authentication issue. Please re-verify whether the credentials used in the **settings.xml** for the Artifactory repository is correct. Just to rule out it's not an issue with API key or the encrypted password being used, try using the plain-text password once through your local settings.xml file.

Comment: only for this antifactory I have the issue.